# Validate AD user can login using SSSD on SuSE

Tags: linux, bash, security, authentication, sssd

I have a requirement to validate if a given user can login to a machine. I don't know their password, but the script can elevate to root using `sudo`. All the users are AD accounts using SSSD.

Everything I've found just validates if the user is valid or not, such as using
`id -u`. Doing `sudo -lu` doesn't work if the user has never logged in before and only shows their `sudo` permissions. I've also tried using `ldapsearch`, but that only queries the AD server to see if they have the correct profiles, but not necessarily on that server.

Comment: What's the distinction you're drawing between "the user is valid" and "the user can log in"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've added some formatting codes to try to improve readability (see [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting). You might want to clarify why `id -u` doesn't satisfy the "can login" requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Create in the Domain a group with the users you want to allow in the machine and use it in the key **simple_allow_groups** explained below.

In the **/etc/sssd/sssd.conf** Add/Modify the following keys:

```
access_provider = simple # This will allow you to control who can log in the computer using the simple_allow_groups.
simple_allow_groups = groupname1, groupname2 # Domain groupnames allow you to limit the log on permission for just the members of the groups in this option.
```

Edit the sudoers (using visudo) and add:

```
%groupname1 ALL=(ALL)      NOPASSWD: ALL
```

This will allow the user to run any command. If you want to limit the commands allowed, see the examples in the sudoers file.